# Correct way to use Ionic's social-sharing plugin?

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework

I am trying to implement Ionic's social sharing plugin into my app, but I'm having issues.

This is the error I get:

[image]

Here is my component.ts

```
import {SocialSharing} from '@ionic-native/social-sharing/ngx';

export class SettingsPage implements OnInit {
  code: string = null;

  constructor(
    private socialSharing: SocialSharing
  ) {}

  ngOnInit() {}

  shareCode(code) {
    this.socialSharing.canShareViaEmail().then(() => {
      // this.socialSharing
      //   .share(`Here is your code: ${code}`)
      //   .then(() => {
      //     log.debug('code has been shared?');
      //   });
    });
  }


}
```

Here is my package.json

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "^8.2.14",
    "@angular/core": "^8.2.14",
    "@angular/forms": "^8.2.14",
    "@angular/http": "^7.2.16",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^8.2.14",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^8.2.14",
    "@angular/pwa": "^0.803.25",
    "@angular/router": "^8.2.14",
    "@angular/service-worker": "^8.2.14",
    "@biesbjerg/ngx-translate-extract-marker": "^1.0.0",
    "@fullcalendar/core": "^4.4.0",
    "@fullcalendar/daygrid": "^4.4.0",
    "@fullcalendar/interaction": "^4.4.0",
    "@fullcalendar/resource-common": "^4.4.0",
    "@fullcalendar/timegrid": "^4.4.0",
    "@ionic-native/core": "^5.22.0",
    "@ionic-native/in-app-browser": "^5.22.0",
    "@ionic-native/social-sharing": "^5.22.0",
    "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "^5.22.0",
    "@ionic-native/status-bar": "^5.22.0",
    "@ionic/angular": "^4.11.10",
    "@ionic/pro": "2.0.4",
    "@ionic/storage": "^2.2.0",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "^12.1.2",
    "@sentry/browser": "^4.6.6",
    "angular2-counto": "^1.2.5",
    "angularfire2": "^5.4.2",
    "cordova": "^9.0.0",
    "cordova-android": "^8.1.0",
    "cordova-plugin-browsertab": "0.2.0",
    "cordova-plugin-compat": "1.2.0",
    "cordova-plugin-device": "^2.0.3",
    "cordova-plugin-inappbrowser": "3.1.0",
    "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard": "^2.2.0",
    "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": "^3.1.2",
    "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": "^5.0.3",
    "cordova-plugin-statusbar": "^2.4.3",
    "cordova-plugin-whitelist": "^1.3.4",
    "cordova-plugin-x-socialsharing": "^5.4.0",
    "cordova-universal-links-plugin": "^1.2.1",
    "cordova-universal-links-plugin-fix": "1.2.1",
    "core-js": "^2.6.10",
    "es6-promise-plugin": "^4.2.2",
    "firebase": "^5.11.1",
    "ionic": "^5.4.16",
    "jam-icons": "^2.0.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.15",
    "messageformat": "^2.3.0",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "ngx-toastr": "^9.1.2",
    "ngx-translate-messageformat-compiler": "^4.6.0",
    "ngx-ui-loader": "^7.2.2",
    "rxjs": "^6.5.4",
    "uuid": "^3.4.0",
    "web": "0.0.2",
    "zone.js": "~0.9.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/architect": "^0.803.25",
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.803.25",
    "@angular-devkit/core": "^8.3.25",
    "@angular-devkit/schematics": "^8.3.25",
    "@angular/cli": "^8.3.25",
    "@angular/compiler": "^8.2.14",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^8.2.14",
    "@angular/language-service": "^8.2.14",
    "@biesbjerg/ngx-translate-extract": "^4.2.0",
    "@ionic/angular-toolkit": "^2.2.0",
    "@ionic/app-scripts": "^3.2.4",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.8",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "^2.0.8",
    "@types/moment": "^2.13.0",
    "@types/node": "^10.17.17",
    "codelyzer": "~4.5.0",
    "cypress": "^3.8.3",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~3.1.4",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^2.1.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.2",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "^5.4.3",
    "ts-node": "^8.6.2",
    "tslint": "~5.12.0",
    "typescript": "3.5.3"
  },
  "description": "An Ionic project",
  "cordova": {
    "plugins": {
      "cordova-plugin-whitelist": {},
      "cordova-plugin-statusbar": {},
      "cordova-plugin-device": {},
      "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": {},
      "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": {
        "ANDROID_SUPPORT_ANNOTATIONS_VERSION": "27.+"
      },
      "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard": {},
      "cordova-universal-links-plugin": {},
      "cordova-plugin-browsertab": {},
      "cordova-plugin-inappbrowser": {},
      "cordova-plugin-x-socialsharing": {
        "ANDROID_SUPPORT_V4_VERSION": "24.1.1+"
      }
    },
    "platforms": [
      "android"
    ]
  }
}
```

I've been trying different for several hours but I just don't know what I'm missing. Is there a special module to include or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add [Social Sharing](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/social-sharing) to **app.module.ts** under `providers`.

```
import { SocialSharing } from '@ionic-native/social-sharing/ngx';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  entryComponents: [],
  imports: [],
  providers: [
    ...
    SocialSharing,
    ...
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Answer (score 0):

VERY IMPORTANT! Update for an issue in Android resolved by me ie: @dipesious

You will get an array of different packages as a .catch(error)
This means you did not add QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES permission to your manifest. Add this to your Android manifest file:

congratulations BUG RESOLVED...

Comment: Who is `dipesious`?

Comment: This answer does not appear to be related to the original question. The error you described sounds different. It's good that you want to share your experience but you might be able to find a more relevant question to post your answer on, or if none exists you can create your own question and answer it.